# pip install package only when not already found

Tags: makefile, pip

I install a github package in my makefile:

```
dependencies: ## installs the github repo
    pip install git+https://git.github.com/author/repo
```

Now I really would want to do this only one time!
This is, because now every time I run this, it fetches, clones and installs the package what takes a long time.

Is there a way to tell pip to only install this package if it not already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no for VCS (git in your case) repositories. `pip` has to know name and version of the package so it needs to clone the repo.

To avoid constant re-downloading create a wheel from the package. `pip` can infer names and versions from wheel names.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I can only guess what i should do now. Should I include a `#egg=repo-2.0` or something to make this work?

Comment: I experimented yesterday and it didn't work for me. Glad it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I altered your answer with an example, but it got rejected somehow..